# set animation between frames of animationdrawable

Tags: android, animation, bitmap

I have one `ImageView` and two image to bitmaps which are set to the imageview temporarily like this:

```
    AnimationDrawable staticAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
    staticAnimation.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp[0]),150);
    staticAnimation.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp[1]),150);
    staticAnimation.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp[2]),150);
    iv.setImageDrawable(staticAnimation);
    staticAnimation.start();
```

**Question:**

How can I add animation while changing bitmaps? for instance first image fade out and the second one fade in smoothly.

- I cannot use `ImageSwitcher` or `PageViewer`
- It is important for this app to do all the animations in one View (currently imageview)

thanks for any hint, help,...

Answer (score 1):

Use TransitionDrawable to add animation while changing bitmaps inside an ImageView like this :-

```
Drawbale[] drawables = new Drawable[x];
TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = new TransitionDrawable(drawables);
imageView.setImageDrawable(transitionDrawable);
transitionDrawable.startTransition(5000);
```

Comment: Please inflate drawables with your own drawable and "x" is the size of the array.

Comment: If you are using bitmaps, convert bitmap into a drawable by converting bitmap into BitmapDrawable.

Comment: Use setCrossFadeEnabled() method of transitoon drawble to toggle cross fades

Comment: thanks it works but how can I change the transition (by default it uses fade transition but I need translate)? Moreover only the first 2 drawables are presented, why?

Comment: TransitionDrawable cannot be used for Translate animations. Material design does not recommend Translate animation to change / switch images inside an ImageView therefore, they do not provide any API for the same. If you want to do something like that, you have to create your own animations. I'm very sorry I don't have a clue regarding how to create such translate animation to switch / swap between images inside the ImageView but, can suggest you something.

Comment: My suggestion is, to use two ImageViews and show only one at a time. Swap the images between them and animate them while you show / hide them. Or you can even use a ViewPager and swap images inside it very easily by doing any type of transitions.

Comment: You asked "only the first 2 drawables are presented". The reason is TransitionDrawable can transition from one Drawable to another i.e. it can work for two drawables perfectly. If you want to change multiple drawables you can create a work around for the same.